# Проблемы с отображение анимации (css+js) в разных браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, css

возникла проблема с кроссплатформенностью. Изначально проверялось в yandex браузере, без проблем, все идеально.
В опере и мозиле такая проблема: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Анимация улетела вверх :с
Предполагаю, что в хроме тоже могут быть такие проблемы, но не проверял.

Через выполнение кода ниже (на этом сайте, все нормально работает, надеюсь у Вас тоже нормально отобразится, но на всякий случай: полоска под input'ом заполняется градиентом от начала до конца с левой стороны при вводе текста или просто при нажатии на этот input):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этой проблемой

```css
.login-form{
  width: 360px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.login-form h1{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.txtb{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.txtb input{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 40px;
}

.txtb span::before{
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  color: #adadad;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}

.txtb span::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg,#3498db,#8e44ad);
  transition: .5s;
}

.focus + span::before{
  top: -5px;
}
.focus + span::after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="POST" class="login-form"> 
            <div class="txtb">
                <input type="text" name="login" value="">
                <span class="span1" data-placeholder="Username"></span>
            </div>
        </form> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".txtb input").on("focus",function(){
            $(this).addClass("focus");
            });

        $(".txtb input").on("blur",function(){
            if($(this).val() == "")
            $(this).removeClass("focus");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: left: 0 допишите

Comment: и `bottom:-2px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил в `::after` значения `left: 0; top: 100%` и в хроме стало норм. Сейчас в фф проверю.
UPD: В мозиле и яндекс-браузере тоже всё ровно. Сафари под рукой нет :(

```css
.login-form{
  width: 360px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.login-form h1{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.txtb{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.txtb input{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 40px;
}

.txtb span::before{
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  color: #adadad;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}

.txtb span::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg,#3498db,#8e44ad);
  transition: .5s;
  left:0;
  top:100%;
}

.focus + span::before{
  top: -5px;
}
.focus + span::after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="POST" class="login-form"> 
            <div class="txtb">
                <input type="text" name="login" value="">
                <span class="span1" data-placeholder="Username"></span>
            </div>
        </form> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".txtb input").on("focus",function(){
            $(this).addClass("focus");
            });

        $(".txtb input").on("blur",function(){
            if($(this).val() == "")
            $(this).removeClass("focus");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло с моим вопрос. Только теперь другая проблема возникла, когда убираешь курсор, после того как стираешь текст,  полоска пропадает, как раньше появлялась. (В опере)

Comment: Оперы тоже под рукой нет. Сори. Да и как-то не уделяю я опере должного внимания.

Comment: Я понял, не под тот after подставил, но результат был похожий :D Чудеса, спасибо большое :З